# What SQL does Hibernate's @JoinColumns generate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to analyse a legacy app and I've got this annotation in a class called Role.java. I'm trying to work out what the generated SQL for this particular join would look like.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="COMPANY_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false),
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", referencedColumnName="EMPLOYEE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
})
private CompanyPerson person;
```

I'm guessing it would be using aliases, something like this

```
LEFT JOIN person_role ROLEA 
    ON ROLEA.employee_id = PERSON.employee_id
LEFT JOIN person_role ROLEB
    ON ROLEB.company_number = PERSON.company_number;
```

But I'm not sure, and I've only got the source code to go on - no way to build the application and I can't get near the server to turn the logging up enough to get Hibernate to log the SQL. Also had a quick look at the [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) but couldn't figure it out.

Could someone give me an example of how the generated SQL would look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@JoinColumns` annotation is defining the many-to-one relationship between the `Role` and the `CompanyPerson` tables, indicating the columns of the composite foreign key.

In your `Role` table you'll find 2 columns, `COMPANY_NUMBER` and `EMPLOYEE_ID`, with foreign keys against the primary key of the CompanyPerson table (expected to be composed by a company number and an employee id).

When hibernate has to select the rows in the `Role` table, and if the fetch type is `EAGER`, it will generate the following `SELECT`:

```
select
    role0_.id as id17_,
    role0_.COMPANY_NUMBER as COMPANY2_17_,
    role0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_17_
from Role role0_
```

and then one `SELECT` for each related row in the `CompanyPerson` table, passing the values the first query returned for the `COMPANY_NUMBER` and `EMPLOYEE_ID` fields :

```
select
    companyper0_.COMPANY_NUMBER as COMPANY1_18_0_,
    companyper0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE2_18_0_,
    companyper0_.information as informat3_18_0_
from CompanyPerson companyper0_
where companyper0_.COMPANY_NUMBER=? and companyper0_.EMPLOYEE_ID=?
```

If you force the join to avoid the N+1 queries, with a fetch join, you obtain the following select:

```
select
    role0_.id as id17_0_,
    companyper1_.COMPANY_NUMBER as COMPANY1_18_1_,
    companyper1_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE2_18_1_,
    role0_.COMPANY_NUMBER as COMPANY2_17_0_,
    role0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_17_0_,
    companyper1_.information as informat3_18_1_
from Role role0_
    inner join CompanyPerson companyper1_
        on role0_.COMPANY_NUMBER=companyper1_.COMPANY_NUMBER and role0_.EMPLOYEE_ID=companyper1_.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

You should execute something like the following code to generate this query:

```
List<Role> roles = (List<Role>)session.createQuery(
        "from Role role join fetch role.person person").list();
```

I hope this can help you understand the `@JoinColumns` annotation.

Comment: I added the way to avoid the N+1 generated SELECTs.

Comment: Using joins is actually better for me too, because I need to run this all as one query through an SQL client ultimately. In my original question I used two join statements using aliases, but I should have just used "inner join xxxxx and yyyyy" as per your example. Thanks again!